# setTimeout doesn't seem to be calling the function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

The code worked great until I added the setTimeout. Now, no matter how I attempt to call the functions in setTimeout ( `setTimeout(function(){fadeOut()},1000);` `setTimeout("fadeOut()",1000);` etc ) it doesn't seem to get to the function at all.

I'm a Javascript newbie so any and all help is appreciated =]

javascript code:

```
var slideArray = ["slide1","slide2","slide3","slide4","slide5","slide6"];
var currentSlide = null;
var current = null;
var done = false;

function fade(newSlide)
{
    if(currentSlide === null)
    {
        currentSlide = slideArray[0];
        document.getElementById(currentSlide).style.opacity = 1.0;

        for(var i=1;i<slideArray.length;i++)
            document.getElementById(slideArray[i]).style.opacity = 0.0;
    }

    current = document.getElementById(currentSlide);
    done = false;
    do
    {
        window.setTimeout(fadeOut,1000);
    } while(done == false);

    currentSlide = newSlide;
    current = document.getElementById(currentSlide);
    done = false;

    do
    {
        window.setTimeout(fadeIn,1000);
    } while(done == false);
}

function fadeOut()
{
    if(parseFloat(current.style.opacity)-0.1>.0000001)
    {
    current.style.opacity = parseFloat(current.style.opacity) -0.1;
        done = false;
    }
    else
    {
        current.style.opacity = 0.0;
        done = true;
    }
}

function fadeIn()
{
    if(0.9-parseFloat(current.style.opacity)>.0000001)
    {
        current.style.opacity = parseFloat(current.style.opacity)+0.1;
        done = false;
    }
    else
    {
        current.style.opacity = 1.0;
        done = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably successfully setting up several million timeout handlers.

Comment: No syntax errors or error messages logged in the console right?

Comment: be sure that when you call it the functions are defined and i agree with @Pointy

Comment: I don't think the function is ever firing because it is stuck inside that do while loop forever waiting.  You are able to create the handler, but never recieve the response because you are in that loop.

Comment: The code just declares some variables and some functions, but it doesn't use any of them for anything, so if the code doesn't do anything, that's exactly what it's expected to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use this structure:

```
do
{
    window.setTimeout(fadeIn,1000);
} while(done == false);
```

Because the code in the `setTimeout()` runs sometime LATER, your value of done will NEVER be changed and this loop will run forever.  And, as long as it runs, the `setTimeout()` never gets to fire either (because javascript is single threaded).

Instead, what you should do is launch the next `setTimeout(fadeIn, 1000)` from the `fadeIn()` function if you aren't done.

```
function fadeOut()
{
    if(parseFloat(current.style.opacity)-0.1>.0000001)
    {
        current.style.opacity = parseFloat(current.style.opacity) -0.1;
        setTimeout(fadeOut, 1000);
    }

    else
    {
        current.style.opacity = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that javascript is single-threaded, so your setTimeout'et functions will not be called until it is finished running the current script. Which will never happen since you're in a loop that's never gonna end (untill you're out of memory from all those setTimeout's). Just call setTimeout once and let the function return. And forget the idea of waiting for it to have happened.